# the argument type 'string' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'list widget '

Tags: flutter, list, dart

how to get my data in the transaction class to present it in my wedget?
it keep showing "the argument type 'string' can not be assign to parameter type'list'.
how do i solve this problem? i keep facing problem with map() function. since im beginner in this field can any one please enlighten me

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:taskmangment/transaction.dart';
import './transaction.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(taskmangment());
}

class taskmangment extends StatelessWidget {
  //list of data from backend
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(id: 't1', titel: 'new shoe', amount: 5, date: DateTime.now()),
    Transaction(
        id: 't2', titel: 'weekly Groceries', amount: 2, date: DateTime.now())
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('first application')),
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                elevation: 5,
                child: Text('chart!'),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: transactions.map((tx) {
                return Card(
                  child: Text(tx.titel),
                );
              }).toString(),
            )
          ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

// this is my transaction class

```
class Transaction {
  String id;
  String titel;
  double amount;
  DateTime date;

  Transaction(
      {required this.id,
      required this.titel,
      required this.amount,
      required this.date});
}
```

Comment: Why .toString() added in return of widget, remove .toString() or replace to .toList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `toString()` with `toList()`, like this:

```
Column(
      children: transactions.map((tx) {
        return Card(
          child: Text(tx.titel),
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
```

Comment: thank youuuu, that solve my problem but why? im following this tutorial and it said "we are using map function to change the list to string".

Comment: column's children expect List of Widget, so wen we use `map` on list it return `Iterable` so at the end we call `toList()` to change `Iterable` of widget to list of widget.